# Multiple measures using the same filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

There is a table with tens of millions of rows. I have a multiple rows card showing measures which are all calculated over that same table using the same filter like this:

```
Numero Datas = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Registro Contábil'[RCF_DT_REGISTRO_CONTABIL]); 
        FILTER('Registro Contábil'; [FiltroConta] = 1)
    )
```

`[FiltroConta]` itself is a measure.

```
FiltroConta = IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK('Registro Contábil'[ContaDebito])) 
    || 
    NOT(ISBLANK('Registro Contábil'[ContaCredito]))
    ; 1; 0)
```

The problem is that it is very slow. I guess it is because the filter is reapplied for each measure. If so how to have the filter applied only once for all measures?

Answer (score 0):

If it's something that you'll be using frequently, I'd suggest making `FiltroConta` a calculated column on the `Registro Contábil` table and then write your measures like this:

```
Numero Datas =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Registro Contábil'[RCF_DT_REGISTRO_CONTABIL] );
    'Registro Contábil'[FiltroConta] = 1
)
```